# Where I can find this pubsub subscription on the cloud storage bucket for Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm replicating data from MySQL to Bigquery. As the first step I have setup **DataStream**, it's copying files to GCS and working fine. Now I want to take data to my final destination  BigQuery, tried to use **Datastream to Bigquery** Dataflow template, but I don't know from where I can get this *Pub/Sub subscription on the Cloud Storage bucket*

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nL4UuFQKy0&ab_channel=GoogleCloudTech) tutorial but it is not updated. I've also checked this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#datastream-to-bigquery) but not sure where I can get it.

[image]

Comment: You should create a notification channel, and then create a pull subscription. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

Comment: If it's that, it's absolutely not clear!!! Let me know, I'm in touch with the Datastream PM.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but now I'm facing a different issue. I have created two datasets `db` and `db_staging`, db_staging is fine and I can see changelog but `db` is empty. 
Also please request Datastream PM on behalf of me for updating youtube tutorials, this tutorial was not old but can't follow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more detailed tutorial for setting up replication to BigQuery, here: https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/implementing-datastream-dataflow-analytics

To understand why `db` is empty we need more information. Is there anything in the Dataflow logs? What is the `MERGE` frequency defined in Dataflow?

I'll see about updating the video tutorial, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).